# Como alterar o valor de um input por uma factory?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Eu tenho um `<input type=file>` e quero adicionar o path da imagem a este input para enviar o formulario para meu webservice. Eu consigo pegar o caminho da imagem através de uma factory e não consigo alterar o valor desse input adicionando o path.

Como eu faço para mudar o valor desse input pela factory ?

**input**

```
<input type="file" ng-model='User.imageFile' id='imageFile'/>
```

**factory**

```
var app = angular.module('starter');

app.factory('CameraFactory', ['$q', function($q) {

    var options = {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: 0,      // 0:Photo Library, 1=Camera, 2=Saved Photo Album        
    }

    var onSuccess = function(imageData) { 
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageData, function(fileEntry) {                
            //console.log(fileEntry.nativeURL);      
            var imageFile = document.getElementById('imageFile');
            imageFile.value = fileEntry.nativeURL;                     
        });    

        var image = document.getElementById('smallimage');
        image.src = imageData;  

    };

    var onFail = function(e) {
        console.log("onFail! " + e);        
    };

    return {
        getPicture: function() {
            return navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess,onFail,options);
    }
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colega, você está abordando o problema sem levar em conta a filosofia do angularjs que é alterar o DOM somente através de diretivas.

Uma factory não deveria alterar o DOM.
Um controller não deveria alterar o DOM.

Você diz que quer *"adicionar o path da imagem a este input para enviar o formulario para meu webservice"*

Então, você está utilizando o input para salvar temporariamente o valor do caminho da imagem e conseguir recuperá-lo de outro ponto em seu código. Você não precisa fazer isso.

Você pode salvar a string do caminho da imagem em uma variável na factory (lastImagePath, por exemplo), ou enviá-la de um callback ou promise após o plugin recuperar a imagem.

Exemplo (não testado!) da opção de callback:

```
app.factory('CameraFactory', function($q) {

    var options = {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: 0,  // 0:Photo Library, 1=Camera, 2=Saved Photo Album        
    }

    return {
        getPicture: function(cback) {
            var onSuccess = function(imageData) {
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageData, function(fileEntry) {
                    if (cback) cback(
                            { success:true,
                              path: fileEntry.nativeURL, 
                              imageData: imageData 
                            }
                    );
                });

            };

            var onFail = function(e) {
                console.log("onFail! " + e);
                if (cback) cback( {success:false} );
            };


            navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, options);
    }
  }
});
```

Então, no seu controller:

```
CameraFactory.getPicture( function(result) {
     if (result.success) {
           // faça algo com result.path e result.imageData
     } else {
           console.log('falhou...');
     }
);
```

Comment: perfeito, funcionou exatamente como eu queria. muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

A modificação que você está fazendo, está fora do escopo do angular, ela é feita diretamente no elemento html. Atualmente, o angular não consegue reconhecer este tipo de alteração e por tanto é necessário solicitar a ele que atualize seu escopo. Para isso você precisará injetar nesta factory o `$rootScope` e executar o seguinte código após alterar o elemento de imagem:

```
var onSuccess = function(imageData) { 
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageData, function(fileEntry) {                
        //console.log(fileEntry.nativeURL);      
        var imageFile = document.getElementById('imageFile');
        imageFile.value = fileEntry.nativeURL;
        $rootScope.$apply()             
    });    

    var image = document.getElementById('smallimage');
    image.src = imageData;  
    $rootScope.$apply()
};
```